# Better way to pass class-reference to an injected instance

Tags: java, annotations, mvp, cdi

I am trying to get a running example of the MVP (Passive-View) Pattern within a JSF2 application using CDI and Annotations.

My goal is to decouple all the relevant projects, meaning that the view resides in a jsf-war-project and the presenter in a separate jar. I am slightly following [Adam Biens example](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2011/11-jan/o11java-195110.html) on Oracle, but I dont want the presenter to know anything about the view-framework (in this case JSF).

My problem is that the presenter should be injected to the view, but the presenter should have a parameter-constructor that gets passed in the current view-instance. So I was hoping that the @Inject-Annotation would allow something like @Inject(this), but it doesnt :-(

I got around this problem by an init-method with @PostConstruct which calls a setter on the presenter and passes it the the current view. I guess this is the closest I can get according to the CDI-specification...feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

**View-Annotation:**

```
@Stereotype
@Named
@RequestScoped
@Target(TYPE)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface View {}
```

**Presenter-Annotation:**

```
@Stereotype
@Named
@Target(TYPE)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Presenter {}
```

**Presenter-Instance:**

```
@Presenter
public class BikeGaragePresenter {

    BikeGarageView view;

    protected BikeGaragePresenter(){}

    public BikeGaragePresenter(BikeGarageView view){
        assert view != null;
        this.view = view;
    }


    public void save(){
        System.out.println(view.getOwner());
    }

    public void setView(BikeGarageView view) {
        this.view = view;
    }   
}
```

**View-Instance:**

```
@View
public class BikeGarageBB implements BikeGarageView {

    @Inject
    private BikeGaragePresenter presenter;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        this.presenter.setView(this);
    }

    private String owner;

    public void setOwner(String owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    @Override
    public String getOwner() {
        return this.owner;
    }

    @Override
    public void displayMessage(String message) {


    }

    public void save(){
        presenter.save();
    }
}
```

**Now here's my question: can I somehow extract this boilerplate code (init-method) into the annotation (somehow similar to Aspects)?** I dont know much about how to write annotations...I usually just use them :-D

EDIT: to be more precise: can I use Annotations as a Decorator?

Comment: Presenter is not annotated with RequestScoped - is that correct? In this case BikeGaragePresenter will be singleton.

Comment: I didnt want to have any dependencies on the actual frontend-technology (e.g. use the same presenter also for a rcp-app). I thought that RequestScope comes from the Servlet-API. But yes, the presenter must not be a singleton (each view needs a fresh presenter).

Comment: Yes it won't be a singleton because the default scope is @Dependendent so each time you'll inject BikeGaragePresenterit will be a new bean.

Comment: Did you considered using the InjectionPoint CDI bean to give awareness of its injection context to your bean ?

Comment: No...I just started using CDI. Could you give an example?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to achieve what you want would be to lazily inject (to avoid cyclic injection) the view in the presenter.  It would look like this :

**Presenter-Instance:**

```
@Presenter
public class BikeGaragePresenter {

    BikeGarageView view;

    @Inject
    @Any
    Instance<BikeGarageView> viewInstances;

    public BikeGarageView getView()
    {
        return viewInstances.get();
    }       

    public void save(){
        System.out.println(view.getOwner());
    }


}
```

**View-Instance:**

```
@View
public class BikeGarageBB implements BikeGarageView {

    @Inject
    private BikeGaragePresenter presenter;

    private String owner;

    public void setOwner(String owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    @Override
    public String getOwner() {
        return this.owner;
    }

    @Override
    public void displayMessage(String message) {


    }

    public void save(){
        presenter.save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try this out later today. My first impression is that this approach is not much different from mine but it looks more complicated (compared to a @PostConstruct method that sets itself in the presenter). Are there any other advantages beside that everything is injected?

Comment: It's a bit different since it brings decoupling (your view doesn't have to access your presenter). It could be enhance to support multiple view (using Qualifiers and an parent class or interface for all views).
You also could create a decorator to implement this function and define the getView() method in the decorator.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The decorator is what I was looking for. May I ask you to enhance your example with this pattern? Is it possible to do this with an Annotation?

Comment: I finally had the time to test your approach and I have a tiny problem with it...or at least Weld does. As far as I understand the injection-code: Any instance that is created by CDI that conforms to the interface will get injected to Instaces and then I grab one. BUT Weld seems to be lost in some kind of a loop. I get a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/weld/util/reflection/Formats$6 and a lot of Debug-output (I added a sysout to the view-constructor) though there should only be one line.

Unfortunately the CDI-book I ordered hasnt been printed yet ;-)